# Java executes but not C++ in Qt 5.7 for Android (worked in prior Qt)

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I have an Android app written in Qt that has the same basic structure as the Qt Notifier example : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html

There is a native droid interface using an extension to class org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.  There is also a QApplication backbone and they communicate bidirectionally via jni.  In Qt 5.2 through 5.5, everything worked fine.  I skipped 5.6, and just upgraded to 5.7.  Now, the Java side works, i.e my Java QtActivity class is launched and displayed, but the app acts like the C++ is non existent!

When I add some qDebug() output to main.cpp it is not displayed on the console at all!  (Yet in Qt 5.5 I can see it with no problem).  I can, however, see qDebug() output from my static C++ function: JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM* vm, void* /*reserved*/ )

If I remove the native Activity by commenting out ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR in my qmake, then the main C++ function is invoked.

What's going on here?  What has changed in Qt to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe that no else has had this same problem!  At least I can't find anyone else reporting this.

I found that if the Java side QtActivity class calls setContentView() from onCreate(), then the C++ main function is never called! This was not an issue until this new version of Qt.  Note that QtNotifier example I referenced in my question doesn't do that, why is why it runs on Qt 5.7 out of the box.

I had to revise my logic so that the Java QtActivity class does it other initialization tasks, but leaves out setContentView() to natively load the ui.  Then the C++ fires off.  From the C++ side, I issue a jni call to the QtActivity class which then uses setContentView().  Note that I have to use a static instance reference to the QtActivity class (which I assign in onCreate), and I have to run that code on the main/ui thread.

Here are some useful code snippets for you to drop into a Java QtActivity class:

```
private static MyQtActivityClass instance_;
private static Handler mainHandler_;
```

...

```
 @Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    instance_ = this;
    context_ = this.getApplicationContext();
    mainHandler_ = new Handler( Looper.getMainLooper() );
}

public static void runOnMainThread( Runnable runnable ) {
    mainHandler_.post( runnable );
}
```

...

```
runOnMainThread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            instance_.setContentView( R.layout.XXXXXX );
        }
    });
```